# Сделать уже запущенный в Linux скрипт как скрин

Tags: linux, debian

Добрый день,

Суть такова:

Запущен скрипт для разворачивания дампа весом в 40+ гб через команду `"mysql -h localhost -u root-p databasename < dump.sql"`.

Процесс продолжается уже несколько дней и есть нужда выключить компьютер.
Можно ли перенести выполнение этого скрипта в состояние (скрина) и выйти из *Putty*?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам не нужно следить за процессом, можно просто свернуть его, нажав `Ctrl+Z`, он приостановится, а потом можно продолжить его работу в фоне командой `bg`, после чего спокойно закрывать putty. Если же есть какой-то вывод логов в консоль и хочется за ним следить, то тут сложнее, но тоже можно, но я щас сходу не вспомню как

Comment: Алсо, перед выполнением любых советов крайне рекомендую сперва проверить всё это на каком-нибудь другом долгоиграющем процессе; вдруг я что-то напутал

Comment: Хотя да, mysql может вывести какую-нибудь ошибку, которую желательно бы увидеть, так что делать как я написал пожалуй не стоит

Comment: Перенести в screen можно с использованием доп.программ. У вас есть возможность установить дополнительные программы (`sudo apt-get install`) в другом окне putty?

Comment: @andreymal тем более делать так не стоит потому что mysql сразу прибьёт SIGHUP'ом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer на mysql не проверял, но cat успешно живёт

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/55880/292034

Comment: @andreymal, если клиент не сбрасывает соединение при закрытии, то это может быть из-за того, что у тебя сервер настроен так, чтобы не сбрасывать мёртвые соединения (что чревато появлениями призраков), может установлен какой-то таймаут и ты просто проверил рано... но на стандартной конфигурации при правильном завершении сессии он должен убиваться.

Comment: Больше спасибо за советы - буду пробовать!

Comment: @tyyylerdurden пробуйте в первую очередь варианты по ссылке от alexander barakin, должно подойти

Comment: @andreymal HUP пристрелит когда пути закроешь